# VLOOKUP SOLUTION

Tags: excel-formula

looking to add total per year for each part.
is this a VLOOKUP combined with COUNTIF?

SPREADSHEET CAPTURE

[image: https://imgur.com/a/xb08dMC]

NEED TO FIND E4 IN COLUMN A TO COUNT COLUMN B WITH DATE YEAR CRITERIA, TOTAL IN COLUMN F=(2019) G=(2020) H=(2021)

Answer (score 0):

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=$E4)*(YEAR($C:$C)=F$1),$B:$B)`

[image]